# How do I force an OpenCV window to redraw in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, imshow, redraw

I am using Open CV 3 with Python 3.
The program lets users select a region of interest with the mouse.

My ROI window is redrawing as the region of interest expands, but not as it contracts.

Here is the function:

```
def update_roi():
    global roi, img, h, w, x, y
    if h>0 and w>0:
        roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, 0:3] #take a slice from original image
        cv.imshow("ROI", roi) #show the new region of interest.
```

When w is increased, the ROI window redraws as expected and the image grows smoothly. But when w is decreased, annoyingly, the residue of the previous draw is still displayed.

I tried blanking out the ROI by filling it with zeros using a np.array.zeros() ..this made it flicker but the roi was still inaccurate on decreasing width.
As pointed out in some other posts, I also tried using cv.waitkey(50) to give things a chance to draw. No help either.

I tried forcing redraws by calling cv.imshow multiple times... did not solve this problem however.

I should point out that it's merely aesthetic, the code still writes the correct shrunken ROI to disk as an image.

But I'd really like to know:
Is there a way to force redraws in Open CV windows using Python?
Thanks very much
Lindsay

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. Depending on your exact requirements you may find that calling `destroyWindow()` or `destroyAllWindows()`([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=destroywindow)) right before `imshow()` works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.